# Defining Integer value in Where clause for JPQL query using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to fetch joined data from two tables using spring boot and spring data JPA. In my joining query I defined where clause with a integer condision userId=value. But I am getting the error like

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to com.spacestudy.model.Users
```

In my repository I added query like ,

```
    @Query("SELECT u.nuserId , ur.ninst_id FROM Users u JOIN u.roleUserRoleMappingMappingJoin ur where u.nuserId = :uid")
    Users findByNuserId(@Param("uid") int uid);
```

And calling from controller like ,

```
@GetMapping("/load")
    public Iterable<Users> load() {
        return (Iterable<Users>) userObj.findByNuserId(670);
    }
```

From this I am able to get result. But why I am not able to retrieve from previous ? What is mismatching here ?
Can anyone help me to resolve this type problem ?

Comment: Why are you using join just simply do findByNuserId and you will get everything . Remove query  and use Users findByNuserId(int uid);

Comment: But I need data on particular condition. Later I am using DTO to send response.

Comment: But you are simply getting data on Nuserid. you already have relationship b/w user and UserRoleMapping , so there is no need of join you will simply do Users findByNuserId(int uid);  and the user.roleUserRoleMappingMappingJoin.ninst_id

Comment: you are getting error because you are trying fetch two columns u.nuserId , ur.ninst_id and you are mapping them to user. But in user ninst_id column is not there

Comment: So what I can do here If I need nuserId from second table without joining ? any othre way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid joins. Thats the beauty for JPA/Hibernate.

Repository Code

```
Users findByNuserId(int uid);
```

Service Code

`Users  user=repository.findByNuserId(uid)`;

```
int nuserId=user.nuserId;
int ninst_id=user.roleUserRoleMappingMappingJoin.ninst_id;
```

Comment: Yes I got your way. I will try definitely. But in the same way I already have another query. That is working properly. Why this only not working. I am updating my question.Can you please look on that?

Comment: I updated there.Are you not able to see?.That query properly working . For here I just copied. But Here I only got type mismatching error at run time

Comment: In Users findByNuserId(@Param("uid") int uid); you are trying to map with user object and user object does not have ninst_id  column thats why its throwing exception

Comment: How I can then define a object type parameter ? Is that possible ?

Comment: simply do in repository  findUsersByRoleUserRoleMappingMappingJoin(UserRoleMapping  role) and pass userrole as parameter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178917/discussion-between-ap-singh-and-mr-deveng).